# Speaking at CLSxItaly

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-promotion

I will be speaking as part of a panel on how to moderate online communities at [CLSx Italy](http://clsxitaly.org/) on November 25th.

If anyone is interested in attending, I have a discount code just for Skeptics.SE. Please go to [Eventbrite](https://www.eventbrite.it/e/biglietti-clsxitaly-roma-25-novembre-37317754408) and use code `CLSxIT50`.

Hope to see some of you there :-)